# Usar propiedad Time highcharts React

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, momentjs

Intento que para el día 28 de Octubre, que se hace el cambio de hora, me aparezca pintado en un gráfico `highcharts` dos veces la hora 02:00.

He conseguido que me funcione con javascript y usando la librería momentjs: http://jsfiddle.net/nachfren/ozhqcj39/

El problema viene cuando lo intento pasar a mi proyecto con PrimeReact.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'
import {Moment} from 'moment-timezone'  // <- Visual Studio me dice que no estoy usando esta librería.

export class Consumos extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {

        let options = {
            time: {
                timezone: 'Europe/Madrid'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Consumos'
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'MWh'
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },

            series: [{
                name: Medida,
                data: [[66.11],[73.48],[50.65],[38.69],[70.14],[69.65],[14.66],[5.01],[4.23],[4.94],[3.06],[2.37],[1.98],[1.91],[1.83],[1.61],[1.56],[1.56],[1.57],[1.53],[1.55],[1.56],[1.52],[1.51],[1.98],[1.91],[1.83],[1.61],[1.56],[1.56],[1.57],[1.53],[1.55],[1.56],[1.52],[1.51],[1.98],[1.91],[1.83],[1.61],[1.56],[1.56],[1.57],[1.53],[1.55],[1.56],[1.52],[1.51],[1.98],[1.91],[1.83]],
                pointStart: Date.UTC(2018, 9, 27),
                pointInterval: 36e5//Horario (3600 * 1000)
            }]
        }

        return (

        <div className="ui-fluid">
                <HighchartsReact
                    highcharts={Highcharts}
                    constructorType={'stockChart'}
                    options={options}/>
        </div>
    );
    }
}
```

De esta manera me pinta la hora `02:00` solo una vez. ¿alguien ve el error que tengo?

Como recordatorio decir que la línea de abajo me indica que no se está usando.

> import {Moment} from 'moment-timezone'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He conseguido hacer funcionar el gráfico con React haciendo el siguiente cambio:

En lugar de importar así:

```
import {Moment} from 'moment-timezone';
```

Lo he importado así:

```
window.moment = require('moment-timezone');
```

Motivo:

- Highchart espera un identificador global llamado `moment`.

Otra solución es

```
import {moment} from 'moment-timezone';
window.moment=moment;
```

Demo funcionando [aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pawer13-moment-react-highchart)

Comment: Me ha funcionado con `window.moment = require('moment-timezone');`